# SAS-code can't scan the parameters from Bat file which came from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, sas, batch-processing

I am trying to run my SAS code from my VBA-code by using bat file (batch run). So the system should work like this: First VBA-code sends some parameters to bat file, then the bat file sends this parameters into my SAS code. Then the bat file executes my SAS code.

However, obviously the Bat file can not send the parameters into my SAS-code, they don't exist according to the SAS-system. When I run my VBA-code (which runs also the Bat file), I get an error message like

> This window is unavailable in line-mode.

The VBA code is like this:

```
Public Sub RunSASCodeViaBatFile()
    ...
    Parameter settings here 
    ...

    Dim cmdString As String: cmdString = batPath & batFile & " " & SASFilePath & " " & SASFile & " " & SASOutputPath & " " & YearMonth
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 2
    wsh.Run cmdString, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
End Sub
```

The commands in batch file looks like this:

```
Some General SAS settings in bat file like:
set sas="C:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2(32-bit)\sas.exe" -autoexec
....

Settings for the input parameters
set SASFilePath=%1
set SASFile=%2
set SASOutputPath=%3
set YearMonth=%4

if %debug%==1 (
   echo %thisscript%: Debug: Execute SAS program
   echo %thisscript%: Debug: sas=%sas%
)   
%sas% -sysin "%sasfilepath%\%sasfile%" -SYSPARM "%SASFilePath%#%SASFile%#%SASOutputPath%#%YearMonth%" -log "%SASOutputPath%\log\%SASFile%_%date_time%.log" -nosplash -icon -no$syntaxcheck -rsasuser -noprint
if %debug%==1 echo %thisscript%: Debug: errorlevel=%errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
  echo %thisscript%: Error: Execution of SAS program returned code %errorlevel%
  exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

And finally the SAS code scans (reads in) the batch parameters like below. I am trying to read batch parameters with `SYSPARM` command:

```
    %LET sasfilepath = %SCAN(&SYSPARM, 1, '#');
    %LET sasfile = %SCAN(&SYSPARM, 2, '#');
    %LET sasoutputpath = %SCAN(&SYSPARM, 3, '#');
    %LET perdate = %SCAN(&SYSPARM, 4, '#');
```

I think the problem happens when the SAS code try to scan the parameters `batPath`, `batfile`, `SASFilePath`, `SASFile`, `SASOutputPath`, `YearMonth`.  Because the batch file can use these parameters correctly to create log names or to find paths with these parameters.

So anyone has any idea about why my SAS can't scan the bat-parameters?

Comment: Why don't you just have the batch file write the variables to a file and then use a DATA step to read the file to create the variables.

Answer (score 1):

From this note, looks like your batch SAS job is trying to do something that requires an interactive session, such as using DM commands. http://support.sas.com/kb/44/705.html

The %let statements you showed should not cause this problem. I would look elsewhere in the SAS code.

Actually first I would remove the -icon option on the SAS invocation. That option probably expects an interactive session with windows to minimize.

If you don't see a suspect in your SAS code after that, try brute force debugging. Comment out all of your SAS code and see if it works. Then uncomment half of it and see if it breaks. Repeat.

If by small chance the %let statements do throw this error, please show the parameter values you are passing in SYSPARM.

Comment: thanks. Now I am debugging and I commented out almost everything. Only beginning path descriptions are left like `%let Server=ServerPath;` and `libname mylib "&Server\ExcelFolder";`. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the -icon option on your SAS Invocation?  I think that is the cause.

Comment: Hmm... Can you get it working from a command prompt?  Just to remove all the VBA and bat file stuff.  So just submitting the SAS command, does it work?

Comment: now I found a solution. I added `%let SASFilePath=%sysget(SASFilePath);` in my SAS code. So finally I can transfer my variables from Excel to SAS via batch. However, I realized something else. That error window doesn't appear when I click and run the batch file directly. It appears when I run the process inside VBA-code, even if everything works just fine

Comment: Glad you got it working by switching to use %sysget to read environment vars instead of passing the values in SYSPARM.  If you want to debug further, I would suggest. 1. Get SAS program working that you can invoke from command prompt. 2. Get invocation working hard coded into bat file (no environment vars).  3. Get invocation working using environment vars in the bat file.  4. Get invocation working calling the bat file from VBA.  And see where along the line it breaks, then debug that. Just a thought.

Comment: Try adding the -NOTERMINAL option to the command line for SAS.